# When is there a need for an sql package used?

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400, rpgle

what is purpose of SQLPKG?
How would I create one on the IBM i?
when would I use one on the IBM i environment?

Regards,
Jemrug

Comment: Have you checked the documentation here: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=sql-package-support

Comment: Well I am confused , traditionally a sql package can have a source , that it has header and body and inside it has a body , where you define procedures. So hence for my confusion? IBM i talks about adding them like triggers...

Comment: @jmarkmurphy SQL packages on IBM i really used to bind application programs to relational database, if the tables in your programs are across multiple databases then makes its easier? is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On IBM i the SQL package is built by the compiler and contains stuff like access plans for the SQL statements. if the program is intended to just use the local database, the package is built into the program, but if the program is intended to use a remote database, the package is built on the remote system as an external object of type *SQLPKG. It is mostly automagic on IBM i.

Comment: when a table is altered , cross referencing to see where its used when sql packages are concerned is really not applicable?

Comment: It might be. `DSPPGMREF` gives you the ability to search sql packages for usages.